# Do the bonuses to attack/damage rolls for unarmed strikes from the Eldritch Claw Tattoo and Insignia of Claws magic items stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, stacking

I'm playing a level 11 monk/barb in D&D 5e. (I've put 8 levels into monk and 3 into barbarian.)

I recently got the [Eldritch Claw Tattoo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/eldritch-claw-tattoo) from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (p. 126), and I also have the [Insignia of Claws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/insignia-of-claws) (ToD, p. 178; HotDQ, p. 94). These magic items both add a +1 bonus to the attack and damage rolls of my unarmed strikes.
Would this allow me to add a +2 to my the attack and damage rolls of my unarmed strikes?

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Please don't reiterate arguments that have been made on meta (multiple times) in the comments of a question. It's not helping anyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Yes, these stack.

The rules for [combining game effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#CombiningGameEffects) on p. 252 of the DMG - added in the [DMG errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DMG-Errata.pdf) - state (emphasis mine):

> **Different game features can affect a target at the same time.** But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again. Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items.

Since Eldritch Claw Tattoo and the Insignia of Claws are different magic items, they can affect you at the same time. The restriction on stacking applies to features **with the same name**.